# How to resolve "Using 'Get Element Attribute' without explicit attribute is deprecated" in robot framework using selenium library

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

This works and returns exactly what I want:

```
*** Variables ***
${HOME_LOGO}=  css=#header > nav > div.header-gutter > div > img

*** Keywords ***
Home logo is visible
  Element Should Be Visible  ${HOME_LOGO}
  ${logo_src}=  Get Element Attribute  ${HOME_LOGO}@src
  log  ${logo_src}
```

However, I am getting a WARN when I run it: Using 'Get Element Attribute' without explicit attribute is deprecated

I have tried several approaches, but have not been able to resolve the warn message AND get the information I want into ${logo_src}. I am looking for the img src.

What is the best way to either handle the warn or get the img src from the element in the xpath?

Thank you - I'm very new to robot framework and selenium but not new to test automation. Also new to stackoverflow.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. :)

Comment: Welcome :) and this RTM may help you - [Get Element Attribute: "Passing attribute name as part of the locator is deprecated since SeleniumLibrary 3.0. The explicit attribute argument should be used instead."](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) - e.g. don't add the target attribute in the locator separated by @ - just put it in an argument by itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you - I think I don't have the syntax right, I've not been able to get it to work. I'll keep working at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have changed how this keyword works from when it was originally designed. Instead of appending the attribute to the locator, provide it as an argument:

```
${logo_src}=  Get Element Attribute  ${HOME_LOGO}  src
```

(note: there needs to be two or more spaces before `src`)